# Custom Model not updating in catalog_product_save_after event

Tags: magento2, products, model

I ran into weird issue. I am trying to update my custom model/table in catalog_product_save_after event but it always creates new entry in the DB instead of updating older one.
I'm doing this way :

```
        $model = $this->_qpcFactory->create();
        $id = $this->getQPCId();
        if($id)//update
          {            
            $model->load($id);
//if I print model here it is working fine, i-e same model loaded that I want.
          }
            $model->setData($data);
            $model->save();
//but here new record is created in my custom table instead of updating the one I loaded above.
```

Is it something to do with the event I am using because this works smooth in Save controller?
Any clue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `catalog_product_save_commit_after` as the transaction from saving the `catalog_product` has not been commit on `catalog_product_save_after`.

Also create a repository or use the resource model of your QPC model to load and save your model.

```
// I assume here you injected the QPC resource model in the constructor
// as "qpcResource".
$qpcModel = $this->_qpcFactory->create();
$id = $this->getQPCId();
if($id) {            
    $this->qpcResource->load($qpcModel, $id);
    $qpcModel->setData($data); // Maybe $data has not the id?
    $this->qpcResource->save($qpcModel);
}
```

Using `setData` with an array completely overrides the data of your model. If you do not need to override the entire data of your model, consider only setting the necessary data instead of overriding everything. Check if `$data` contains the id of the original data of the `$qpcModel`. If not, add it to `$data`. Magento will create a new entry in the db when the `_isObjectNewFlag` on the model is set, or when the id is missing.

Comment: I knew it would be a silly mistake. The `id` wasn't set in `$data`. :)